# Error en suma/resta de checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

Intento hacer una suma de checkboxes. Me sucede que cuando lo pruebo y selecciono alguno de los checkbox en donde se supone que comenzaria la suma, me figura "NaN" lo cual no se que significa ni como solucionarlo. Espero alguien pueda ayudarme. Abajo dejo mi fragmento de codigo HTML y JS. Tambien una captura del error para que puedan ver de que trata.

HTML:

```
<form name="form_merch">
    <ul class="merchandising">
        <li>
            <p>Remera Naturalia</p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" value="25" onclick="if(this.checked) sumar(25);else restar(25)" />
            <label for="cb1"><img src="Imagenes/Remera.jpg" class="merch_img_size" alt="Remera Naturalia" id="remera"></label>
            <p>$25</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>Buzo Naturalia</p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" value="30" onclick="if(this.checked) sumar(30);else restar(30)"/>
            <label for="cb2"><img src="Imagenes/Buzo.jpg" class="merch_img_size" alt="Buzo Naturalia"></label>
            <p>$30</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>Gorra Naturalia</p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" value="10" onclick="if(this.checked) sumar(10);else restar(10)" />
            <label for="cb3"><img src="Imagenes/Gorra.jpg" class="merch_img_size" alt="Gorra Naturalia"></label>
            <p>$10</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>Funda Naturalia</p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb4" value="15" onclick="if(this.checked) sumar(15);else restar(15)" />
            <label for="cb4"><img src="Imagenes/Funda.jpg" class="merch_img_size" alt="Funda para smartphone Naturalia"></label>
            <p>$15</p>
        </li>
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="total_merch" value="0">
        </p>
        <button id="boton_comprar">COMPRAR</button>
    </ul>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var total_merch = 0;

function sumar (valor){
total_merch += valor;
document.form_merch.total_merch.value=total_merch;
}

function restar (valor){
total_merch -= valor;
document.form_merch.total_merch.value =total_merch;

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No hay nada de malo con el ejemplo que colocaste, lo probe y funciona sin problemas.

Comment: @AlbertHidalgo si, tienes razon. Intente probarlo en un CodePen y tambien me funciona. No se por que me muestra "NaN" cuando lo veo desde el navegador. Se te ocurre cual podria ser la causa?

Comment: Puede ser algo muy específico, de todas formas, convierte a número los valores de los inputs, algo como `total_merch += Number(valor);`